# Why use the `+` (plus) or `!` (logical not) operator in an IIFE?

Tags: javascript, iife

I know the typical form of an IIFE is:

```javascript
(function(){/* code */})()
```

However, recently I found a new one:

```javascript
!function(){/* code */}()
+function(){/* code */}()
```

which also work as IIFEs.

I think in the first `!` makes the value a boolean, so the code is equivalent to `true()`, and in the second `+` makes the value a number, so the code is the same as `NaN()`?  But `true()` and `NaN()` cannot possibly work, while the above two forms work well.

How do those two forms of IIFE work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the cases of `!function() {}()` and `+function() {}()` JavaScript will first evaluate the right handside of the given statement/IIFE and then cast the return value of the IIFE to a boolean in case of `!` or to type number in case of `+`.
If the IIFE returns a boolean `!` will negate the return value.

### Example

```js
console.log(
  !function() {
    return "something";
  }()
); 

/**
!function() {
  return "something";
}()

evaluates to

!"something" and not true() or false()

lastly !"something" is equivalent to false
*/
```

Answer (score 2):

The `function` keyword has a duel purpose. Depending on the context you use it in, it either starts a function **declaration** or a function **expression**.

Function **declarations** declare a (hoisted) local variable in the scope of the current function and assign the function to that variable.

Function **expressions** don't, they require that you do *something* with the function immediately. Common examples include assigning it to a property of an object, passing it as an argument to a function (i.e. making it a callback) or using it as an IIFE.

If you try to follow a function **declaration** with `()` then it will error.

```js
function myFunction() {
    console.log("Example");
}();
```

Only function **expressions** can be immediately invoked function expressions. (Well, arrow functions can too, but IIFEs are much older than them).

So to use an IIFE you have to do *something* to change the context the `function` keyword appears in so it is used to create an expression instead of a declaration.

The classic way is to wrap the function in parentheses.

```js
(function myFunction() {
    console.log("Example");
})();
```

But *anything* that makes it an expression will work.

Putting an operator (such as `!` or `+`) in front of the `function` keyword will do that.

While `!` will take the return value of calling the IIFE and turn it into a negated boolean and `+` will turn it into a number **that isn't the point**. There's nothing to the left hand side of the operator so that value is discarded.

It is just a way to make the `function` keyword create a function **expression** that can be turned into an IIFE.

---

Note that the key benefits of IIFEs are also provided by block scoped variables (`let` and `const`) and JavaScript modules, so there isn't much reason to use an IIFE at all in 2022.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to get a function to execute immediately upon its definition. The common thing is that you must make sure the function is not interpreted as a function *statement*, but as a function *expression*.

By prefixing the function keyword with a unary operator like `!` or `+` or any other unary operator (`~`, `-`, `void`, ...etc) you avoid that the `function` is interpreted as a *statement*.

Also assignment will work:

```
var x = function(){/* code */}()
```

Or array literal:

```
[function(){/* code */}()]
```

Or passing it as argument to a (cheap) function:

```
Object(function(){/* code */}())
```

Or applying a binary operator, provided the function expression is the second operand and not the first. Here with the comma operator:

```
0,function(){/* code */}()
```